# Mocking laravel contracts

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking

I am using [Laravel contracts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/contracts) in my application to decouple the application code from the framework code. Mainly though, I find it easier to see when a class is doing too much at a glance - our legacy projects suffered from 'hidden facades' being peppered all over the place.

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory as File;

class MyClass extends Command
{
    public function __construct(File $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->file->put('/here.txt', 'stuff');
    }
}
```

The problem comes when trying to mock them. If I mock the contract an run the test, the mock is not used in place of the contract.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory as File

MyClassTest
{
    public function my_example_test()
    {
        $fileSystem = m::mock(File::class);
        $fileSystem->shouldReceive('put')->once();
        $this->app->instance(File::class, $fileSystem);

        $this->artisan('my-custom-command');
    }
}
```

When I inspect the `$file` property I can see of course that laravel used the concrete implementation (obviously). Except when I try and mock the concrete implementation, it too is used instead of the mock.

```
use Illuminate\Config\Repository as File;

MyClassTest
{
    public function my_example_test()
    {
        $fileSystem = m::mock(File::class);
        $fileSystem->shouldReceive('put')->once();
        $this->app->instance(File::class, $fileSystem);

        $this->artisan('my-custom-command');
    }
}
```

I tried mocking both but this doesn't work either. I am doing integration tests hence why I am calling the command using artisan. Apparantly there is a slightly [easier way for unit tests](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/mocking-contracts) but this does not help in my situation.

I should note that using the above ways of mocking my own classes works perfectly and the mocks are injected in the respective classes by the Laravel container. It also works for the [underlying facade classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#facade-class-reference) - just not the contracts.

I have also tried the following with no success either.

```
MyClassTest
{
    public function my_example_test()
    {
        $fileSystem = m::mock(File::class);
        $fileSystem->shouldReceive('put')->once();
        $this->app->bind(File::class, $fileSystem);

        $this->artisan('my-custom-command');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Ok this seems to be an issue when mocking classes injected into the constructor of any class that extends the laravel `Illuminate\Console\Command` class. Mocking classes injected into the handle method works just fine.